# mapbox gl - Pbf layer not working in android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-mapbox-gl

I m using react native mapbox gl and added pbf tile like :

```html
<MapboxGL.VectorSource 
  id="idTestSoruce" 
  tms={true} 
  tileUrlTemplates={["url@EPSG:900913_1024@pbf/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"]}>
     <MapboxGL.FillLayer 
      id="idTestLayer" 
      sourceID="idTestSoruce" 
      sourceLayerID="plotm" 
      style={{ visibility: "visible", fillColor: "red"}} 
      minZoomLevel={12} 
      maxZoomLevel={22} 
   />
</MapboxGL.VectorSource>
```

Version info:

```
react-native: 0.59.10
@react-native-mapbox-gl/maps: 7.0.8
```

It is working perfectly in ios but in android getting following error:

```
Error while updating property 'tms' of a view managed by: RCTMGVectorSource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change following in source :

From :

```
@ReactProp(name="tms")
public void setTMS(RCTMGLRasterSource source, boolean tms) {
   source.setTMS(tms);
}
```

To:

```
@ReactProp(name="tms")
public void setTMS(T source, boolean tms) {
   source.setTMS(tms);
}
```

Ref. : [issue link](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/issues/817)